# How to transpose the data from select query conditionally

Tags: sql

I've a select query which return me data as follows:

```
---------------------------------------
PartCode  | ParentCode  |  Flag  |
---------------------------------------
ABC       |  XYZ        |  null  |
---------------------------------------
PQR       |  XYZ        |   Y    |
---------------------------------------
```

Now I want to transpose this based on the flag as follows:

-PartCode with Flag as Y should be labelled as criticalPart & other as SecondaryPart.

-There will always be two rows on which I want to apply this condition.

```
---------------------------------------------
ParentCode | CriticalPart  |  SecondaryPart |
---------------------------------------------
XYZ        |  PQR          |    ABC         |
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code below to achieve the result.

```
  select ParentCode
    , Max(case when flag = 'Y' then PartCode end) as CriticalPart
    , Max(case when flag is null then PartCode end) as SecondaryPart
    from table 
    group by ParentCode
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54e6a3/2)

Comment: Aggregate function, smart !

Answer (score 1):

I would go with two sub query and a join on the parent code

```
SELECT  critical.ParentCode, 
        critical.PartCode as CriticalPart, 
        secondary.PartCode as SecondaryPart
    FROM (
        SELECT  ParentCode, PartCode 
            FROM Table 
            WHERE Flag IS NOT NULL
    ) critical
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ParentCode, PartCode 
            FROM Table 
            WHERE Flag IS NULL
    ) secondary ON critical.ParentCode = secondary.ParentCode
```